# How to update C# version in Ranorex Studio?

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, ranorex

My project in Ranorex Studio (v8.3.1) is using .NET Framework 4.5.2 and C# 5.0. I want to leverage the features of newer C# versions e.g. [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). So I want to upgrade my Ranorex Project to at least C# 6.0.

The problem is that when I go to Tools > Project Upgrade, I only see that .NET 4.6 and C# 5.0 are available in the dropdown for the upgrade.

What do I have to do get the latest/newer version of C# in Ranorex Studio so that I can upgrade my project within the Ranorex?

Comment: which version of ranorex studio are you using?

Comment: @Gauravsa I am using Ranorex Studio 8.3.1

Comment: and what c# 6.0 features are you trying to use?

Comment: Another developer has checked in some code which includes some C# 6.0 specific code e.g. [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). I do have a workaround for this but I would like to update to C# 6.0 too. Also, he has the C# 6.0 available on his machine but none of us could figure out why I don't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as per their website. Ranorex Studio is built on SharpDevelop 4, which has a max .NET version of 4.5 and C# 5.0.

Ranorex APIs must maintain compatibility with SD 4, so that they can compile with .NET 4.5. A person can work with higher level of .Net but Ranorex Studio won't be able to work and features like code completion and error marking won't be available.

More here: https://www.ranorex.com/forum/ranorex-8-and-net-4-6-1-t11884.html

Comment: Thank you for the reference. But our another project is using C# 6.0 within Ranorex and everything is working perfectly fine for that. They also have C# 6.0 available within Ranorex. So, my assumption is that I should be able to do that too within the Ranorex.